# Is it possible to configure Bash to use similar prompt settings that I use with Zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh

Is it possible to get the same prompt settings I have in Zsh in Bash?

```
unset PROMPT
unset RPROMPT
promptinit
PROMPT='>'
RPROMPT='[%F{green}%(5~|%-1~/.../%3~|%4~)%f]'
```

e.g. my prompt in zsh looks as follows:

```
>            [/local/.../Downloads/tcl8.5.13/generic]
```

and disappears when the command I type would collide with the right prompt. (I don't care about any color (it should just differ from my black background))

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.

PS1=$(printf "%*s\r%s\n> " "$(tput cols)" 'righty tighty' 'lefty loosey')

But it's a far cry from RPROMPT in zsh